# Add Id or other attributes to ASP.NET MVC 3 Html Helper Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I add attributes to a html helper textbox.

I've tried this:

```
@Html.TextBox("username", new { id = "username" })
```

This seems to put 'id=username' in the value field of the textbox. I want to add an Id to my textbox.

Thanks.

Comment: @Bryan has provided the answer but there are specific attributes like class which conflicts with .net code. so, use @ to escape the string like  `@Html.TextBox("username", Model.Username, new { @class = "username" })`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter (`new { id = "username" }` in your example) is the initial value (value attribute) of the TextBox. The third parameter is the actual htmlAttributes:

```
@Html.TextBox("username", Model.Username, new { id = "username" })
```

Comment: how would you add an attribute that contains `-` in its name ..? I tried placing `@` before and with double quotes. No luck

Comment: @shashwat You can use an underscore instead of an hyphen, ASP.NET MVC will do the substitutions for you. For more complexe cases, you could always use the `TextBox` method override that takes a `RouteValueDictionary` instead of an anonymous object.

Answer (score 1):

while `new { id = "username" }` as the 2nd parameter is valid, you will need to add `@` to attributes that are also keywords, like `class`.